# Running cumulative SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large(ish) member DB where I am trying to do some future projections of membership. As such, I am trying to get a cumulative total of the number of members that are entered onto the system every month.

I have the following code

```
select  YEAR(datejoined) as YDJ,
    MONTH(datejoined) as MDJ,
    COUNT(MONTH(datejoined)) as CDJ,
    SUM(Count(Month(DateJoined))) as SCDJ
From Member
Group by YEAR(datejoined), MONTH(datejoined)
Order by YEAR(DateJoined) asc, MONTH(datejoined) asc;
```

However it is throwing an error as follows:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

What I would like the SUM function to do is calculate the number of total members  in the DB from the start to that point (include that month's new members).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You can't perform an aggregate on an aggregate. SUM(COUNT()) is probably the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by year, month along with cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310066/order-by-year-month-along-with-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused by `SUM(Count(Month(DateJoined))) as SCDJ`

*aggregate function* can't contain *aggregate function* in one select.

You need to write a subquery to solve it

if you want to *cumulative SUM* you can use *window function* with `SUM`

```
SELECT t.*,SUM(CDJ) OVER (ORDER BY YDJ ,MDJ) as SCDJ
FROM (
    select  
        YEAR(datejoined) as YDJ,
        MONTH(datejoined) as MDJ,
        COUNT(datejoined) as CDJ
    From Member
    Group by YEAR(datejoined), MONTH(datejoined)
) t 
Order by YDJ asc, 
         MDJ asc
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Getting an error message on the ORDER BY function, and the ) t naming (both MSG 102 - incorrect syntax)

Comment: @Clauric How about `SELECT t1.*,
    SUM(t1.CDJ) OVER (ORDER BY t1.YDJ ,t1.MDJ) as SCDJ
FROM (
    select  
        YEAR(datejoined) as YDJ,
        MONTH(datejoined) as MDJ,
        COUNT(*) as CDJ
    From Member
    GROUP BY 
      YEAR(datejoined),
   MONTH(datejoined)
) t1
ORDER BY t1.YDJ asc, 
         t1.MDJ asc`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you want:

```
select YEAR(datejoined) as YDJ, MONTH(datejoined) as MDJ,
       COUNT(*) as CDJ,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(datejoined), MONTH(datejoined)) as running_CDJ
    SUM(Count(Month(DateJoined))) as SCDJ
From Member
Group by YEAR(datejoined), MONTH(datejoined)
Order by YEAR(DateJoined) asc, MONTH(datejoined) asc;
```

Cumulative sums are available in SQL Server 2012+.  In earlier versions, you can use `APPLY`:

```
with t as (
      select YEAR(datejoined) as YDJ, MONTH(datejoined) as MDJ,
             COUNT(*) as CDJ,
             SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(datejoined), MONTH(datejoined)) as running_CDJ
      From Member
      Group by YEAR(datejoined), MONTH(datejoined)
     )
select t.*, t2.running_cdj
from t outer apply
     (select sum(CDJ) as running_CDJ
      from t t2
      where t2.ydj < t.ydj or
            t2.ydj = t.ydj and t2.mdj <= t2.mdj
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. Getting an error message(MSG 102 - incorrect syntax) on the ORDER By function

Comment: @Clauric . . . What version of SQL Server are you using?